# LINQ: Concatenate/Union multiple sequences

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Given the following class

```
public class Entity
{
  public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and in my repository I want to get all (distinct) `Tag`s of all `Entity`s, is there a way to do this other than

```
public class Repository()
{
  public IList<Tag> GetAllTags()
  {
    List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
    var entities = _session.GetAllEntities();
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
      tags.AddRange(entity.Tags);
    }
    return tags.Distinct().ToList();
  }
}
```

such as

```
public class Repository()
{
  public IList<Tag> GetAllTags()
  {
    _session.GetAllEntities().Select(x => x.Tags).....Distinct().ToList()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Repository()
{
  public IList<Tag> GetAllTags()
  {
    var entities = _session.GetAllEntities();
    return entities.SelectMany(e => e.Tags).Distinct().ToList();
  }
}
```